# What does "each pathway define an independent genotype" mean?

Tags: biochemistry, bioinformatics, metabolism, pathway, metabolomics

In a section of [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bit.260310611/abstract;jsessionid=859164671D3BA23A8D51FDEA4E7639E6.f01t04) paper.

> However, if the question of independency is posed in the
>   form: “Does each pathway shown define an independent
>   genotype?,” then each of these three pathways is indeed
>   independent. This is the way that MPS defines the independence
>   of pathways.

What does “Does each pathway shown define an independent
genotype?,” mean?

Comment: Pathways cannot define a genotype. They are product of the genotype and they define the phenotype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat outside my field, but basically it seems they're defining the independence of the three hypothetical metabolic pathways in two different ways:

- Mathematically the pathways are not independent since P₃ is a combination of P₁ and P₂.
- Biologically the pathways are independent since each requires a different combination of enzymes and therefore genes (the genotype). This is the method used in MPS.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I don't know, the answer you gave seems satisfiable so i would go with it...